# MySQL(?): what converter may have changed " ä " to " ¨a "?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

This is more out of curiosity than practical need....

This was just found in one of our older databases: in a text field, all `ä` ([German umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29)) characters were displayed as `¨a` (similar with other umlauts).

As possibly every other developer that has to deal with texts, I have seen my fair share of garbled text because of latin-1 / Unicode shenanigans, but I never encountered this strange sign... And it's hard to google...

As far as I know, the table started as [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and was later migrated to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The text in question may have been copied from a Microsoft Office document.

Technically, `ä` (unkown bytecode/encoding) got converted to two (!) UTF-8 characters, `¨a` (C2A8 61 / UTF-8 as hex).

Comment: What byte sequence are you seeing?  Could this be a "combining diaeresis" (unicode character 308) followed by an a?

Comment: it's indeed the "diaresis" (whatever that may be ;) ) - C2 A8 in utf8 hex bytes

Comment: That's called "transliteration".